# regex to match a string that could extend over several lines

Tags: regex, textmate

I have examples in a text document line this:

```
 set (  blah blah blah )
```

and

```
 set ( blahlblah
 blahlbal )
```

and

```
set ( blah
blah
blah
blah
blah )
```

I am using text mate and want to find these and replace with nothing

I got this to work with one line but stumped on how to do this over multiple lines. I tried this:

```
 SET \(.*\n.*\)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simpler:

```
set \([^)]+\)
```

Unless the set contains nested sets, that should work.

Comment: There is also the case where the set contains something such as string literal, and the regex can fail due to the string literal containing `)`. But then the question does not mention this, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if textmate can do this

```
 ^\s*set\s*\([\S\s]*\)[^)]*$

 --------------------------
 ^ 
 \s* set \s* 
 \(
    [\S\s]* 
 \)
 [^)]* 
 $
```